# Formatting data and removing keys

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, ecmascript-6

I have another data question. Data processing is a real weak point of mine, so trying to understand it better.  I have a variable called `data` which contains the following

```
[
    {"ID":1,"process":"quick","owner":"John","decission":"Admin","status":"failed","flag":"red"},
    {"ID":2,"process":"standard","owner":"Mary","decission":"Admin","status":"failed","flag":"blue"},
    {"ID":3,"process":"slow","owner":"John","decission":"Management","status":"active","flag":"red"}
]
```

It is essentially an array of Objects.  I am trying to turn this into an array whereby the object keys are the first row of the array, and the content follows.
However, I do not require the ID or flag. So the above would look something like this

```
[
    ["process","owner","decission","status"],
    ["quick","John","Admin","failed"],
    ["standard","Mary","Admin","failed"],
    ["slow","John","Management","active"]
]
```

So to get the header row, I was thinking about doing something like this

```
const keys = Object.keys(this.data[0]);
keys.splice(keys.indexOf('ID'), 1);
keys.splice(keys.indexOf('flag'), 1);
this.formattedArray.push(keys);
```

To me however this seems like a very step by step process, and then how do I ensure the other data is placed in the correct rows underneath?

What would be the best way to format my initial data to how I now require it?

Thanks

Comment: This is for Google charts so I think they need one array

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First get the keys, then the values based on those keys.

```js
const data = [{"ID":1,"process":"quick","owner":"John","decission":"Admin","status":"failed","flag":"red"},{"ID":2,"process":"standard","owner":"Mary","decission":"Admin","status":"failed","flag":"blue"},{"ID":3,"process":"slow","owner":"John","decission":"Management","status":"active","flag":"red"}];
const keys = Object.keys(data[0]).filter(e => !(["ID", "flag"].includes(e)));
const values = data.map(e => Object.entries(e).filter(([k]) => keys.includes(k)).map(([, v]) => v));
const res = [keys, ...values];
console.log(res);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: auto; }
```

Answer (score 1):

Since i see that you don't have an array of all your headers you can create it by using:

```
const headers = Object.keys(data[0]).filter(header => header !== 'ID');
```

After you have all your headers you can go on and extract the data:

```js
const data = [
    {"ID":1,"process":"quick","owner":"John","decission":"Admin","status":"failed","flag":"red"},
    {"ID":2,"process":"standard","owner":"Mary","decission":"Admin","status":"failed","flag":"blue"},
    {"ID":3,"process":"slow","owner":"John","decission":"Management","status":"active","flag":"red"}
];

const headers = Object.keys(data[0]).filter(header => header !== 'ID');
const result = [headers];
data.forEach(row => result.push(headers.map(header => row[header])));

console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's another way of doing it using *Array.prototype.reduce*

```
const result = this.data.reduce((accumulator, currentValue) => {
    if (accumulator && accumulator.length === 0) {
        const headers = Object.keys(currentValue).filter((key) => key !== 'ID' && key !== 'flag');
        accumulator.push(headers);
    }
    accumulator.push(Object.values(currentValue).slice(1));
    return accumulator;
}, []);
```

Answer (score 1):

While the other solutions work. I would do

```
const excludeItems = new Set(["ID", "flag"]);

function generateTableData(data) {
  const headers = Object.keys(data[0]).filter(item => !excludeItems.has(item));
  const items = data.map(item =>
    Object.entries(item).reduce((res, [key, value]) => {
      if (!excludeItems.has(key)) {
        res.push(value);
      }
      return res;
    }, [])
  );
  return [headers, ...items];
}
```

[check it out here](https://codesandbox.io/s/wizardly-spence-hp7fv)